# What is the probability that it will take 25 die rolls until "5" is rolled 5 times?

Tags: probability

A standard six-sided die is rolled until "5" is rolled 5 times.

What is the probability, that it will take 25 rolls for that to happen?

X = the amount of die rolls before we see "5" for the 5th time.

For example, in this sequence("1", "5", "3", "4", "5", "2", "3", "3", "5", "5", "4", "5"), **X = 12**

I need to find **P(X = 25)**

Comment: *Hint:* Among the first $24$ rolls there need to be exactly $4$ occurrences of the number 5 and the $25$'th roll needs to be the number 5.  Think binomial distribution.

Comment: Or the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you for such quick hints. I really appreciate it. I've got an answer: 0.03564. 
Am I right?

Comment: Yes that is correct answer.